# iterating through the hierarchy of objects - C# - linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, for-loop, data-structures

I have an object (say A) with hierarchy as below,

> obj A --> Contains list of obj B --> Contains list of obj C -->
>   Contains list of obj D

Given the obj A, i need to get the list of all obj D in total, irrespective of its association with obj C and obj B. something like `List<D> GetAllofD(A a)`

Can you please suggest me the best way to get it done - don't want to use multiple `for loops`. Any better approach using linq?

Comment: a.b.SelectMany(b=>b.c.SelectMany(c=>c.d))

Comment: a.b.c.Select(c=>c.d).ToList();

Comment: @feiyun0112: Thanks, it works fine. Is there a way to handle null condition for collections in this same linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handle null condition for collections

```
a.b == null ? new List<D>() : a.b.SelectMany(b=>b.c==null ? new List<D>() : b.c.SelectMany(c=>c.d))
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @feiyun's comment, repeated application of [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) can be used to progressively rollup all levels of the class hierarchy:

```
var allDsInTheTree = new A().Bs.SelectMany(b => b.Cs.SelectMany(c => c.Ds));
```

Given the class hierarchy:

```
public class D { public int Id { get; set; } }
public class C {
    public IEnumerable<D> Ds { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public IEnumerable<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
public class A
{
    public IEnumerable<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

`SelectMany` at a single level would be something similar to:

```
var cs = new List<C>();
foreach (var b in a.Bs)
{
   cs.AddRange(b.Cs);
}
```